# Can a surjective function whose image satisfies a cardinality constraint be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider a function
$$ f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \{y\in \mathbb{R}^m \mid \|y\|_0 \le d < m, d \in \mathbb{N}\} $$
and suppose $f$ is surjective (or at least that the image of $f$ is not a subset of just a single $d$-dimensional coordinate hyperplane). Here $\|y\|_0$ denotes the $L^0$-norm, i.e. the number of non-zero elements. Can $f$ be continuous? My intuition says no, but I'm not able to convert it into a proof.

Comment: I think the  Hahn–Mazurkiewicz theorem found on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) might give yes as the answer. It at least seems like those spaces should be the image of the unit interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely possible. Consider a countable family $F$ of disjoint open balls of radius one in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that their centers have their $d$ first coordinates vanishing.

Consider the set $I$ of all embeddings $\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ which just add some zeroes to the coordinates -- $I$ is finite with cardinality $\binom{m}{d}$. Partition $F$ into countable subsets $F=\coprod_{i \in I}{F_i}$, and define bijections $\psi_i: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow F_i$. Let $\chi$ be a continuous nonincreasing function $[0,1) \rightarrow [0,1]$ with compact support and $\chi([0,1/2])=\{1\}$.

We define $f$ as $0$ outside the $B \in F$, and, if $x \in \psi_i(n)$ (we denote $c_{i,n}$ the center of $\psi_i(n)$, for $n$ positive integer, $i \in I$), $f(x)=n\chi(\|x-c_{i,n}\|)i(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$.

Then $f$ is continuous and onto your specified arrival set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your construction has definitely helped me to see why it is possible. Altough I'm still lacking intuition.. 
Two questions: 1. I don't really see, where the scaling $n$ in f comes from?
2. I would expect that the function $\chi$ has to decay to zero as the argument converges to 1, since we want $f(x)$ to approach zero as $x$ converges to a boundary point of some ball $B \in F$?

Comment: @ARedder: Yes, $\chi$ decays to zero as the argument converges to $1$, that's why I wrote its domain this way and specified it had compact support. The purpose of the scaling is to manage to (when considering balls far enough) get all points of $L^0$-norm at most $d$, not just those of small enough norm -- by construction, in the balls, $\|(x_1,\ldots,x_d\|)_2 \leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Now maybe allow me a follow up question. Ultimately I'm interessted in differentiability of such a function. Can such a function be differentiable?

Comment: @ARedder: Sure, just take a smooth $\chi$.

Comment: Hm, I need to think about that. Mainly, whether such a construction is practical for my purpose, i.e.  using the total derivative explicitly. Thank you again for your help!